# Physical CHECK Front Side - Question

Tags: banking, bank-account, check, online-banking, checking-account

Would anyone please be so kind to tell me which address is **under** the name of financial institution which is located on the **top** of **front side** of check? Is this address the address where the letter containing the check should be **mailed to** or is this address the **address of the branch** where source of funds account (on this account debit happens so from this account money is taken) is hold? Your answer will surely be the same regardless of type of check. Thank you!

Comment: My checks do not have the banks address, only mine. Can you clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to understand?

Comment: JoeTaxpayer: Out of trillions of possible examples, I will choose the one which you see (the link) at the end of THIS comment. As you can see the address under the name of financial institution holding the account FROM where are funds to be taken/debited (payer's = check writer's account) is ''Reina Victoria 21, 30204 Cartagena'' but I wonder whos mailing address is this? See the bold text of my primary message for both addresses possibilities. http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TwHP-dCxAaM/UaNpEF0aJXI/AAAAAAAAAEI/COLcuzd8x2E/s1600/Cheque.jpg

Comment: You might want to offer a country tag.

Comment: i have no idea what do you mean, i am only asking which address to use

Comment: Check formats may vary by country. Since you posted a link to a non English check example, I suggest you put a tag, telling us what country you are in. Members get a bad rap assuming where a member lives. I prefer to ask.

Comment: answer on my question would be the same regardless of country

Comment: You're assuming consistency across countries. There is no such guarantee.

Comment: Given the legendary "watermelon check" that is, an order to pay from a bank account physically written on a watermelon, I doubt the bank address is a key piece of information.

Comment: Check on odd objects are officially no longer accepted. (No more sending the IRS"the shirt off your back"); that was one of the rule changes the banks negotiated in exchange for processing checks in a reasonable time. A bank _ can _ honor such a check if they want to (I know someone who once cashed a blackboard), but it doesn't have to be accepted by the bank or the payee.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, that is the address of the person that __wrote the check = the person who is *paying* the money (= *your address* if you write the check). In this example, it is '...2063 Main Street...'

You mail the check to the *recipient*, the person who *gets* the money. His name is supposed to be in the line *PAY TO THE ORDER OF*, but it does normally not contain any address, just a name; in this example the recipient is 'Sample Company'.

The check does not carry the recipient's address anywhere; only the envelope has it. If you are sending someone money, you will have to ask them where to send it to.

[image]

Some checks have the bank's name printed on the top right, but that has no influence; it is basically an advertisement ('Your bank Name'):
[image]

Comment: Aganju. No, the account holder's address (home address if personal account or company address if business account of payer) is located more at the top of check's front side but on the top LEFT side. The one I am asking for is more in the middle (close to the right side) of TOP side (front side of check). I clearly said that i am asking for address located right under the name of financial institution (front side of check).

Comment: It can only be the bank's advertisement. Checks are printed in batches before, how could the recipient name/address be printed on them? You don't know who gets them until you write on.

Comment: No, I am using my own check printer including self inking endorsement stamp tool as well as software desktop. I don't know which address is supposed to be under name of the bank.

Comment: See the linked image OP offered. It's a non-english check, which I can't understand. Still, I don't know the point of the question.

Comment: I guess you can print whatever you want in those places, as it has no meaning to the receiving bank. They care about the account and routing numbers in the bottom, and the amount. They should also care about the date and the recipient name, but they seldom do. Everything else is whatever you want, flowers, advertisements, bible citations, etc.

Comment: It is USA check.. the link i gave to JoeTaxpayer is only an example to show my question. Aganju, no its not like whatever i want. It has to be exact and correct address but i don't understand which one.

Comment: who told you it has to be _an exact and correct address_? (but didn't tell you which one???) That is just not correct, and makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: ok i guess you are in same situation as me - you don't know the answer. Thank you anyway

Comment: No - I am sure that there is no answer because the question is based on an incorrect assumption. I have received and written thousands of checks, and not a single one had anything there that was of any importance. You insist that for some reason it must have a meaning and must be right, but you never stated where this conviction comes from.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking (offtopic) which printer and software are you using and where are you getting papers with all security features from?

Comment: @Aganju nice try, and +1 from me. She should ask her bank, and they'll tell her she can put her address or leave it blank. They'll know her account from the number, the address is meaningless.

Comment: There's bank's name and address can also appear in other places on the check; mine includes that in the place where "First Niagra" appears in your top example. The address of the person writing the check is optional; I explicitly choose to have it printed on mine because many companies will ask that the address be written in by hand if it isn't already there. Other aspects of the check format are tightly regulated; these addresses aren't. At least that is true in the US. The answer may be different elsewhere, which is why people keep asking for a country to be specified.

Comment: @Brenda, lasercheck.com in NY, and a simple brother laser printer. You need to select the proper checks that are made for laser printers.

Comment: keshlam i have never spoken in my FIRST message about the address of person writing the check. You misunderstood my question. Aganju those checks are useless - they don't belong to any financial institution.

Comment: The financial institution gets imprinted when you order the checks. Sorry, but I am getting the impression that you don't understand much of check printing. Talk to someone who understands what you are trying to do, and get some instructions.

Comment: i don't understand much, thats correct and i admit it. But im still waiting for the answer on my primary question

Answer (score 3):

The address under a bank's name on a check, if there is one, is generally going to be the contact address of the bank. That will be true no matter where on the check the bank's name appears.

The address of the person or business the account belongs to, if present, will appear under their name. This information block is typically near the top left corner the check, so it will be visible as the return address if the check is mailed in a "window envelope" designed for this purpose.

The address the check is being mailed to, if it appears on the check, will generally appear low on the check and to the right, so it will be visible as the destination address when the check is mailed using a "window envelope" designed for this purpose.

If that isn't the answer you were looking for, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is a standard check. To complete the order, I need to enter the bank routing number, my account number, name address, and phone, if I wish. The name of the bank is required for the order, but does not appear on the printed check.

[image]

For checks you print, this will be no different. It's your name, and address, not the bank's, that goes on the check.